# Ethernet adapter 100 to 10

Tags: ethernet, speed

We have device that works with 10 Mb. Some of the customers have 100 Mb, so our device causes problems. To change our device to support 100 Mb is going to take time and cost a lot, so is there any adapter from 100 Mb (or higher) to 10 Mb?

Comment: Yes this is called a 10/100Mb switch...

Comment: "We have device that works with 10Mbit" ... "to change our device to support 10Mbit gonna take time and cost a lot"  makes no sense.

Comment: It's not 100% clear but my interpretation is that his employer is making some kind of embedded device that only supports 10 Mbps and that modifying the design to support higher speeds and putting that modified design into production would be difficult expensive.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It rather depends on what exactly the "problems" are.

If the problem is that the customers port doesn't support 10 Mbps (uncommon right now but may well get more common in the future) then a simple Ethernet switch will do the trick.

On the other hand if the problem is that there is too much broadcast (or effectively broadcast) traffic for a 10Mbps device to cope then inserting another switch isn't going to help. You will need something that can allow the legitimat traffic to your device through while filtering out the unwanted broadcasts. Often a "home router" works well in this role with it's "lan side" facting your device and it's "wan side" facing the noisy network.

Answer (score 0):

No such device exists, as to my knowledge.
To be honest auto negotiation should work fine. It was standardised as part of fast Ethernet but is  backward compatible with 10base-T.
If auto negotiation doesn't work why not setup port where device is plugged to 10Mbps.

Otherwise you can use 10/100 switch between both devices.